# Why does A && B doesn't work in the Makefile when it works in the terminal?

Tags: c, makefile

I've been having troubles with this Makefile :

```
SRCS            =       gnl/get_next_line.c \
            $(wildcard parsing/*.c) \
            $(wildcard libft/*.c) \
            $(wildcard *.c) \

OBJS            =   ${SRCS:.c=.o}

FLAGS       =   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g

NAME        =   cub3d

LIBS        =   -lm -lX11 -lXext -std=gnu99 $(wildcard mlx/*.a)

RM      =   rm -rf

all     :   ${NAME}

3DLIB       :   ${OBJS} 
            ar rcs cub3d.a ${OBJS}
            ranlib cub3d.a

$(NAME)     :
            ${3DLIB} && gcc -o cub3d ${FLAGS} cub3d.c cub3d.a -I. -g ${LIBS}
```

When I try to `make`, the terminal returns this error :

```
&& gcc -o cub3d -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g cub3d.c cub3d.a -I. -g -lm -lX11 -lXext -std=gnu99 mlx/libmlx_Linux.a mlx/libmlx.a
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "&&" unexpected
Makefile:35: recipe for target 'cub3d' failed
make: *** [cub3d] Error 2
```

Which is weird because if I just run `make 3DLIB  && gcc -o cub3d -Wall -Wextra -Werror cub3d.c cub3d.a -I. -g -lm -lX11 -lXext -std=gnu99 mlx/*.a` (which seems to me to be the same command) raw, it works just well. I've tried different syntaxes in the Makefile to try to make it work, but have come short.

Could someone show me the problem ?

Comment: 3DLIB is not defined.  It is a rule, not a variable.

Comment: It's defined just above. ```3DLIB       :   ${OBJS} 
            ar rcs cub3d.a ${OBJS}
            ranlib cub3d.a```

Comment: Change to  `$(NAME) : 3DLIB` instead

Comment: @Morgade: The line `3DLIB       :   ${OBJS}` does not define a symbol named `3DLIB`. It is a rule for making a target named `3DLIB`.

Comment: @stark It works insofar as the error changes. If I do that it just gives me a slew of undefined reference, which doesn't happen when I raw dog the command in the terminal, which confuses me greatly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't know what you mean by "symbol"

Comment: When you ran this manually, the shell saw two commands: first was `make 3DLIB`, and then it saw `gcc -o ...`.  What's happening is you're thinking that `make` saw the whole thing and are trying to include this in a recipe, but that's not how the shell parses command lines.

Comment: @SteveFriedl how do I make it work then ? Even if I put them one after the other on separate lines it doesn't fucntion properly

Comment: Why are you using a PHONY target 3DLIB instead of a real target named `cub3d.a`?

Answer (score 1):

`${3DLIB} && gcc -o cub3d ${FLAGS} cub3d.c cub3d.a -I. -g ${LIBS}` does not work because `${3DLIB}` attempts to use the value of a symbol named `3DLIB` in a command, but there is no symbol with that name.

The line `3DLIB       :   ${OBJS}` introduces a rule that says a target named `3DLIB` must be rebuilt if any of the files in `${OBJS}` have later modifications than a file named `3DLIB` (or if no such file exists). It does not define a symbol named `3DLIB`.

To specify that the `3DLIB` rule is a prerequisite to `$(NAME)`, change the line:

```
$(NAME)     :
```

to:

```
$(NAME)     : 3DLIB
```

Then remove the `${3DLIB} &&` from `${3DLIB} && gcc -o cub3d ${FLAGS} cub3d.c cub3d.a -I. -g ${LIBS}`, leaving `gcc -o cub3d ${FLAGS} cub3d.c cub3d.a -I. -g ${LIBS}`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is one of the things I tried, but when doing that, it gives me a slew of undefined references on one my .a files, which doesn't happen when running the command manually.

Comment: @Morgade Perhaps you need to do `.PHONY: 3DLIB` to tell make it is a phony target, but there is no need for a phony target at all.  Rename the target `cub3d.a` since it is a recipe to build the file `cub3d.a`

Comment: I changed instances of 3DLIB to cub3d.a and the outcome didn't change.

Comment: To be clear, the term _symbol_ above is not standard: if you read the GNU make manual or the POSIX spec they will call these things _variables_ or _macros_ not symbols.  There's no way that running the _exact same_ compile line in make vs the command line will give different behaviors.  All make does, is run the command line just as if you'd typed it in.  So there must be some other difference.

Comment: I recommend you accept this answer, because it did answer your question correctly, and open a new question with your new problem.  Please show the exact compile line make ran and give some examples of the error messages you got.  Note that the _first_ errors in the output are virtually always more important than the last errors.  And, please use cut and paste of exact messages.